# Javascript Date.now() consistency across machines / time zones

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

Let's say I have a node.js server running from New York, and I have a client connected to it from California using a web brwoser. How reasonably can I expect Date.now() called from the client to match Date.now() called from node.js on the server to within ~50-100 ms (assuming they're called at the exact same instant)? Theoretically Date.now() should always be consistent across machines and time zones since Date.now() "returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC" right?

Comment: are you trying to match cleint and server date with some percision/ error?

Comment: are client_date and server dates  close enough with a difference of 50 - 100 ms?

Comment: The client computer's clock can be set to any time. It's unreasonable to expect that they would somehow be exactly synchronized.

Comment: Are you asking if both the server and the client in california request the clock time on the server at the same instant?

Comment: Only if the client and server have the same time... if I change the time/date in the OS then the value returned by `Date.now()` changes to reflect the changes to the underlying OS time.

Comment: Never trust what client says.

Comment: You can probably get a good estimate if you take the client datetime and pass it to the server for a delta calculation, potentially passing the delta back to the client (repeat as often as you feel necessary).  As other have cautioned though, doing so is no assurance that the client does not alter their datetime and mess that up or that the delta / latency will not change over time.

Comment: You simply cannot trust the client time setting AT ALL.  I could be anything.  If you describe the problem you're really trying to solve, we could likely advise what are good options for dealing with the untrusted client time setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot necessarily assume that the client and server time are in sync.

One of the reasons for that is `Date.now()` is based on the system time of the user's OS. You have no control over that, the time may be correct, may be off a little bit or even completely wrong.

You can try that yourself:

```
> Date.now()
1466809144962

> Date.now()
1403650777388
```

I ran `Date.now()` twice, once with the correct time set up in Windows. Then I changed the year of my system clock to 2014 and ran `Date.now()` again.

**Never rely on the correctness of information that is under control of the user without server side validation.**

Comment: If I have two backend cloud instances and one is in Tokyo and the other is in New York and they're both synced to the same time-server but in different timezones. Can I assume `Date.now()` will produce similar results on both? is Date.now() timezone independent, or does changing the timezone affect the value returned by Date.now().

Comment: @AlexanderD'Attore `Date.now` is timezone agnostic, it returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since the unix epoch